# How to setup firefox to display websites in their native language?

Tags: firefox, language

More and more websites consider it clever to display in the language that I set up in Firefox to be my primary language (or the first one in the list of preferred languages). Unfortunately if that happens to be not the native language of said site, it is more often than not a machine-translated version which is more difficult to understand than the native language if I happen to speak it. So is there any way to make Firefox transmit something like "display the site in the native language if it's among the languages I claim to understand, and only if that is not the case bother me with your bad translation"?

**edit** I'd be fine with using a plugin. I guess the first question is however, [*does* HTTP offer any feature to let website inform the browser about their native language such that the browser can decide which `HTTP_ACCEPTED_LANGUAGE` to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11982114/321973)

Comment: It doesn't detect your browser language, it works by geolocation (reverse lookup of your IP) to work out which country you're in.

Comment: @OliverG that's even worse :-/ what if I'm in an internet cafe in a country the language of which I can't understand good enough? It was bad enough seeing that GEMA crap when I still lived in Germany...

Comment: The problem doesn't lie with the browser, the websites often display what they THINK you should be looking at based on your country.

Comment: @OliverG not exclusively according to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1043339/321973), so at least for sites using the browser feedback instead of geoIP there might exist a solution. Anyway, unsolicited translations shouldn't happen - guess I could ask a question on this at [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ok, asking at ux.se: [Shouldn't automated translation be optional?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/24648/7228)

Comment: @OliverG The vast majority of sites do *not* use geolocation to determine the language of the visitor (because, as Tobias has pointed out, it's wildly unreliable) but instead nearly ubiquitously use the `HTTP/1.1 Accept-Language` header sent my the browser, which *is* configurable.

Comment: @OliverG see also http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities

Comment: I disagree with the statement that the vast amount don't use geo. When I am connected through my VPN in Amsterdam, pretty much EVERY site I visit (major or minor) displays in Dutch rather than English, despite no language change.

Comment: @OliverG I don't know enough about VPN to more than guess that this might modify the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`, but to test that: do these sites also display in Dutch when you don't use your VPN but instead change your browser settings such that Dutch is your preferred language? Can you specifically check whether https://modelingguru.nasa.gov/docs (which respects my language setting) does display in Dutch via your VPN even when your browser language setting is English?

Comment: I certainly don't change ANY language settings when I connect via VPN, and it is just a standard windows VPN connection, so I very much doubt it modifies the headers. The page you linked to displays 100% in English through my VPN.

Comment: @OliverG So doubt I, but you never know... That page's content is English, only the framework auto-translates - is e.g. the "Welcome, Guest" message English as well? Can you link to one of the site you said are geo-translated? If these are really the majority, the internet is becoming a sad(der) place indeed :-/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see this is not a technical problem. From a technical point of view your browser is correctly configured to request the languages you understand, and sites should respond in one of those languages.

The issue here is that the site(s) in question are relying on machine translation to offer additional languages, but they should only offer those languages if they can verify the intelligibility of the translation. (Especially as you can get machine translation plugins for browsers, offering machine translation without asking is a definite usability no-no).

I'd suggest contacting the site(s) and telling them their translation is worse than nothing and they should stop supplying it.

Comment: so I should start with Microsoft...